# how to detect line breaks in java

Tags: java, text, newline

yes i have read a few of the other posts on line breaks but they are not helping me.

my Java program is supposed to read a .PHP file and split the source code into a line by line format. the problem is that i cant seem to really distinguish one line break from another.

i tried to use /n   didnt work....
i tried to use /r/n   didnt work.....

here is an example

```
step_B = step_A.replaceAll("\n", "XXX");
```

i tried to replace the line breaks with the word XXX but it didnt work.

here is a sample of the php i wanted to split, i managed to separate the lines using ; as delimiter but i got to refine it a bit more now.

```
$ALL_AUTH = mysql_fetch_row($author_lookup);
    //preparing to display the output in the table
    echo "<tr>";
```

i wanted it to output something like this

```
INFO:  $ALL_AUTH = mysql_fetch_row($author_lookup)

INFO:  //preparing to display the output in the table 

INFO:  echo "<tr>"
```

but instead i get this

```
INFO:  $ALL_AUTH = mysql_fetch_row($author_lookup)

INFO:  //preparing to display the output in the table  echo "<tr>"
```

the app cannot seem to detect that there is a newline after the comment ends at the word "table". is there a way to do this ? preferably without hardcoding the word table or anything like that.

Ohhhh i found the mistake, i used a transform via some regex on the block of code at an earlier stage and that messed up the newlines.... the code block became one massive line of text ! hence no line breaks 
thanks for your time guys !

Comment: "\n" separator is used on Windows. You can always get the line separator used by your current OS by [System.lineSeparator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) - if you are on Java 7. For the older versions you can go with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. Just note that this will be useful only if the files are created on the same OS as you have.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have the data already in a String:

```
String[] lines = string.split("\r\n|\n|\r");
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Or read the lines directly from a file:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfilename"));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Java 7+ has a convenience method to read lines directly from the filesystem:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("myfilename");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Java does not do automatic charset detection, so you are responsible for setting the charset correctly when reading a text file; otherwise characters may not be read correctly.  Don't forget to be tidy: .close() your file handles.

Comment: This or directly use a `BufferedReader` to read the text file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a solution. You are right in the fact that /n does nothing. However, java separates lines using `\n`. Note the backslash instead of a slash.

Try using `\n` instead of `/n`

EDIT

Actually, I just re-read your code. According to that you did it properly. Just make sure your actual code is like that. Otherwise, this answer does not help you, but it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Java class you use to read the PHP, use something like [BufferedReader.readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). It will grab a line of text for you without you having to worry about `\n` or `\r\n` madness.